# AdSense Auto ads with a SPA powered by Turbo (Hotwired)

Tags: single-page-application, adsense, turbo, turbolinks-5

I have a SPA website that displays ads from Google AdSense.

The framework used for the SPA experience is Turbo (Hotwired) which has superseeded Turbolinks.

The issue I am having is that ads don't display when on subsequent page loads (i.e. when links are followed).
This is related to how Turbo works:

> When you follow a link, Turbolinks automatically fetches the page, swaps in its , and merges its , all without incurring the cost of a full page load.

### Initial page load - Auto Ads

Ads display correctly

### Initial page load - Manual Ad Units

Ads display correctly

### 2nd page loads - Auto Ads

Auto ads are not displaying

### 2nd page loads - Manual Ad Units

Manual Ad Units are not displaying. However, I have managed to fix this issue using the `turbo:load` event listener:

```js
var previousPageVisited = false;
document.addEventListener('turbo:load', () => {
    if (previousPageVisited) {
        var ads = document.querySelectorAll('.adsbygoogle');
        ads.forEach(function (ad) {
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        });
    }
    previousPageVisited = true;
});
```

So the only issue that I am still having is with Auto Ads when following links on the website.
I've tried using the `turbo:before-cache` event listener to see if deleting elements with the `.google-auto-placed` class would help. However, AdSense still doesn't see "new content" on these page requests.

Is there a way to force AdSense to reload or is the only option to disable Turbo?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is still valid and working but this helped me a few years ago: https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/control-ad-loading

Like you disable the initial load and then load ads on demand once you're sure turbo is done.

However, I am not certain this will work with auto ads.